# How would I do this multiple join query using Django's models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this query using Django's model filters. Here's the query:

```
select 
    bs.name, 
    bf.name 
from 
    bs
join 
    bcs on bs.id_bs = bcs.bs_id
join 
    bfc on bcs.bc_id = bfc.bc_id
join 
    bf on bfc.bf_id = bf.id_bf
```

How would I do this using Django's model filters? Thanks!

Edit:

```
class BS(models.Model):
    id_bs = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765, null=False)

class BC(models.Model):
    id_bc = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765)

class BF(models.Model):
    id_bf = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765)

class BCS(models.Model):
    id_bcs = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bc = models.ForeignKey(BC, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    bs = models.ForeignKey(BS, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class BFC(models.Model):
    id_bfc = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bf = models.ForeignKey(BF, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    bc = models.ForeignKey(BC, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the class definitions and/or table structure. i.e., are all of these `id` fields primary keys and/or foreign keys?

Comment: @mattm I added the class definitions. I shortened the class and variable names, hopefully it's not too confusing. I can add more information if you need it.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a ManyToManyField? It should make things easier. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @ecstaticpeon Probably because I added the classes at different times. I'll try it out using ManyToManyFields.